# Highlighting PDF with Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, batch-file, web-applications, web-deployment

I am trying to write a batch file which has html with javascript for a gui. The goal would be the batch file runs VBA gets a TSV file from excel and then highlights some data on a pdf based on the TSV file using JavaScript. I was looking into pdf.js but there are a lot of other solutions i came across. I am new with web development or anything of this sort. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How in the world did you end up with this Rube Goldberg machine of a scenario?

Comment: It is because I am unaware of any other way to do this that would run on client computers without being block by antivirus.

Comment: If you can run VBA then wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Can VBA highlight documents in PDF?